# Bootstrap modal only works after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am experiencing a very strange issue with Bootstrap Modal:

The first time I load my web page with browser cache cleared and click on an icon that should open
the modal it does not open. When I refresh the page and click the icon, the modal appears... When I close the modal and click the icon again it works again.

This is my header code:

```
<link href="libs/jquery/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="libs/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function() { $.noConflict(); )};</script>
<script src="libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

This is my body code:

```
<a id="myIcon">Open Modal</a>

<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">Body</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">Footer</div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

And for those who want to see the full code, this is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myIcon').click(function () {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: Please, provide a demo(Jsfiddle).

Comment: I think you could be having troubles due to duplicate jquery import. Bootstrap needs jQuery and use it for almost anything. If you import it twice, you could have troubles.

Comment: Why have you included 2 different libraries of jQuery?

Comment: I added two libs for compatibility reasons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what is happening. You are forgetting set some attributes in your anchor.

```
<a id="myIcon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</a>

<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">Body</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">Footer</div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

You could avoid your script. In this case your script is simply simulating a click on the modal. Bootstrap already has an event associated to the buttons which have the attributes that I have wrote in your anchor.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // You are triggering a click in your button
    $('#myIcon').click(function () {
        // After the click, you force the modal to be shown
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

You can allow only JS interactions with modals. This way, modals will not have an associated event.

```
<a class="open_modal" data-modal="myModal">Open Modal</a>

<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">Body</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">Footer</div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

You remove the anchor's attributes, and then:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('.open_modal').on('click',function () {
        var idModal = $(this).data("modal")
        $(idModal).modal('show');
    }
});
```

This way, if a .open_modal element is clicked, its data-modal, that represents a modal id, it's used to show the modal.

Comment: Am I able to only allow JS to open a modal? It is necessary for further processing.

Comment: @njlqay I have updated the answer for solving your question